# VS2013 `std::stod` cannot parse infinity

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

When running this example compiled with Visual Studio 2013, an "invalid argument" error is thrown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    std::string inf = "inf";
    try{
        double dinf = std::stod(inf);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

It's my understanding that VS2013 uses the C++11 standard, and [cppreference std::stod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) is tagged with `(since C++11)` and clearly lists (case-insensitive) `INF`/`INFINITY` as valid values.

I've confirmed that I **can** compile/run a program using `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` in VS2013.

So, my question is this: what's the deal? Does VS2013 only support *part* of the C++11 standard? How can one tell what's supported and what isn't? Multiple google searches have yielded exactly nil when it comes to C++ documentation specifically for VS2013.

BTW I would love for the solution to be "use any newer version of VS because Visual Studio 2013 is garbage", but alas I am constrained on this front.

Comment: What "solution" you want? Even it is a bug, nobody will be fixing it in 10 years old and 5 releases back product.

Comment: `Does VS2013 only support part of the C++11 standard?` - correct. [Here's an old table with some details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh567368(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/) this issue is listed as fixed in VS 2015: _The stod() family mishandled INF/NAN inputs by throwing exceptions (DevDiv#1113936/Connect#1098595).  We’re now following the Standards exactly._

Comment: Does VS2013 only support *part* of the C++11 standard? — why of course yes. The dramatic emphasis is unwarranted. Every compiler deviates from the standard.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError thank you for the link, that table is enlightening :)

Comment: @dewaffled thank you for the link, I did not realize this was a known bug, good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to a couple of the commenters, going to repost here as a "solution" for future reference.

I did not know it was a known bug; I'm glad to know I wasn't going crazy and it's actually a known bug.  For some reason or another did not find this page while trying a silly amount of different search queries for this issue, so thank you a bunch to @dewaffled for the reference!

> [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-part-2/) this issue is listed as fixed in VS 2015: The stod() family mishandled INF/NAN inputs by throwing exceptions (DevDiv#1113936/Connect#1098595). We’re now following the Standards exactly. -- dewaffled

Also, I found this table to be quite informative, so thank you as well :)

> `Does VS2013 only support part of the c++11 standard?` - correct. [Here's an old table with some details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh567368(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) -- 500 - Internal Server Error